# How to get a value from the resultset and insert it to another table

Tags: java, sql

I want to get the rs.getInt(1) value and insert that into the param table.

```
public void () {
            result rs;
            int id = 0;

            final String queryStr = "select MAX(id) from IDEAA";
            try {
               connect.connect();
                rs  = connection.executeQuery(queryStr);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    id = rs.getInt(1); // I need to get the value , Here i get the correct value
                }

                final String querySt = "insert into param(id,param_id,value) values " 
                        +  "(" + id + "," + TEST +  ",'"  + "TEST" + "'" + ")" // But when it comes  here it the becomes zero.
               }
```

Could someone suggest me?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: @pals code looks fine, pls debug your code, or put some `log statements` or `syso` statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you could give some more insight in the code (what type is the rs variable and where to get more info on the type (if third party lib))

It still beats me why you would have a while loop since the max id always returns one value the highest.

if might also be worth it to see if you can set the rs to the beginning. (rs.first())

Then try to retrieve the value.

```
public void () {
        result rs;
        int id = 0;

        final String queryStr = "select MAX(id) from IDEAA";
        try {
           connect.connect();
            rs  = connection.executeQuery(queryStr);
            rs.first();

            id = rs.getInt(1);

            final String querySt = "insert into param(id,param_id,value) values " 
                    +  "(" + id + "," + TEST +  ",'"  + "TEST" + "'" + ")" // But when it comes  here it the becomes zero.
           }
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int)

getInt
int getInt(int columnIndex)
           throws SQLException
Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as an int in the Java programming language.
Parameters:
columnIndex - the first column is 1, the second is 2, ...
Returns:
the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value returned is 0
Throws:
SQLException - if the columnIndex is not valid; if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set